# How Prevent auto scrolling when keyboard appears (android & iOS)?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create function that allows blur input on scrolling down, It works well on PC, But on smartphones as soon as the keyboard appears a small scrolling occurs will automatically run the function.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    input.blur();
}
```